# Grand Theft Auto V "Not Optimum Mode"

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v

When I open GTAV it goes directly to a black screen with a floating box that says "Not Optimum Mode Recommended Mode 1920x1080 60 Hz". I have a Samsung S24d300 monitor which is set at 1920x1080. I've updated my NVIDIA hardware. Also, I played the first two missions before this issue occurred.

Comment: Nevermind!   I switched from using Analog to HDMI then set my moniter to dual display and it fixed the issue.

Comment: You should post that as an answer in case anyone else runs into this issue